# Convert a list of objects to a list of Long

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I Have a class as following:

```
Class1 {
    private Class2 class2;
    ...
}
```

I want to convert a list of `Class1` to a list of `Class2::getId()`, this is what I tried :

```
List<Class2> class2List = class1List.stream().map(Class1::getClass2).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Long> class2Ids = class2List .stream().map(Class2::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Isn't there a way to do this in a single instruction ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can chain as many intermediate operations as you please...

```
class1List.stream()
          .map(Class1::getClass2)
          .map(Class2::getId)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or use a single `map(c1 -> c1.getClass2().getId())`